# How to animate the appearance and disappearance of a composable function in Android?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-animation

I'm making a custom `Radio Button` that wraps an animation when I go from selected to deselected and/or vice versa. I am using the `AnimatedVisibility` function of jetpack compose, however I am not getting the expected result.

Notice that in the gif above, despite the buttons changing state normally (selected to deselected and vice versa) the animation is not happening:

[image]

At the moment this code does not animate the buttons despite calling the animation function.

`AnimatedRadioButton`:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun AnimatedRadioButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    isSelected: Boolean,
) {
    if (isSelected)
        FadeAnimatedContainer {
            CircleOptionSelected(modifier = modifier)
        }
    else
        FadeAnimatedContainer {
            CircleOptionUnselected(modifier = modifier)
        }
}

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
private fun FadeAnimatedContainer(
    content: @Composable AnimatedVisibilityScope.() -> Unit,
) = AnimatedVisibility(
    visible = true,
    enter = fadeIn(),
    exit = fadeOut(),
    content = content
)
```

`CircleOptionSelected`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CircleOptionSelected(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    @DimenRes ballSize: Int = R.dimen.ball_size // 24dp
) {
    val size = dimensionResource(id = ballSize)
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .size(size)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(color = MyRed),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        CircleOptionUnselected(ballSize = size / 2)
    }
}
```

`CircleOptionUnselected`:

```kotlin
private val UnselectedBallColor = Color(0xFFF2F2F2)

@Composable
fun CircleOptionUnselected(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    ballSize: Dp? = null
) {
    val size = ballSize ?: dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.ball_size)
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier.size(size),
        shape = CircleShape,
        color = UnselectedBallColor
    ) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AnimatedVisibility` works when `visible` is different between previous and current recompositions. In your code it's always `true`, so no animation should happen.

In your case `AnimatedContent` can be used. Note that using lambda parameter is critical with animation functions, like this one.

```kotlin
AnimatedContent(targetState = isSelected) { targetIsSelected ->
    if (targetIsSelected)
        CircleOptionSelected(modifier = modifier)
    else
        CircleOptionUnselected(modifier = modifier)
}
```

Comment: This drives me crazy: I need to start my animation during the very first recomposition. I already spent 2 hours going through internet and trialling. I found out that it was possible before some Google update but Google cancelled that... But I cannot find any good alternative. Except of launching a background task which changes the state after a brief time... What a crazy solution...